# Socket Connection in IOS

Tags: ios, sockets

Hi I am new in mobile app development. My server is sending me data via socket. I am having a problem with the socket whenever my app is going to the background, I am not getting data from the socket.

I would like to know how I can establish a socket connection which will give me the data all the time regardless of whether the app is in foreground or background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is what push messages are used for. Don't drain the users battery when they are not using your app. If you have some information they need right now: send a push. Otherwise: let them use your app when they choose to.

Answer (score 0):

You cant start with [Socket based iphone app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) awesome tutorial by Cesare Rocchi.